# Restore original file in case of an error

Tags: python, fwrite

I need to write data to a file and overwrite it if file exists. In case of an error my code should catch an exception and restore original file (if applicable)

How can I restore file? Should I read original one and put content i.e. in a list and then in case of an exception just write this list to a file?

Are there any other options? Many thanks if anyone can provide some kind of an example

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will make a copy of the original file and set a flag indicating if it existed before or not. Do you code in the `try` and if it makes it to the end it will set the `worked` flag to `True` and your are go to go otherwise, it will never get there, the exception will still be raised but the `finally` will clean up and replace the file if it had existed in the first place.

```
import os
import shutil

if os.path.isfile(original_file):
    shutil.copy2(original_file, 'temp' + original_file)
    prev_existed = True
else:
    prev_existed = False

worked = False    
try:
    with open(original_file, 'w') as f:
        ## your code

    worked = True
except:
    raise        
finally:
    if not worked and prev_existed:
        shutil.copy2('temp' + original_file, original_file)
```

Answer (score 1):

Any attempt to restore on error will be fragile; what if your program can't continue or encounters another error when attempting to restore the data?

A better solution would be to not replace the original file until you know that whatever you're doing succeeded.  Write whatever you need to to a temporary file, then when you're ready, replace the original with the temporary.

Comment: This is for the assignment purpose. I need to do whatever specification says

Answer (score 1):

1. One way to do it is the append the new data at the end of the existing file. If you catch an error , delete all that you appended.
   If no errors, delete everything that you had before appending so the new file will have only the appended data.
2. Create a copy of your file before starting capturing the data in a new file.